# ASP.NET MVC Почему не удаляется элемент из БД?

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Кнопка HTML

```
<a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin:0' onclick=Delete(" + data + ")>
<i class='fa fa-trash'></i>
Удалить
</a>
```

Функция удаления

```
    function Delete(id) {
        // Объявляем функцию удаления
        if (confirm('Вы уверены, что ходите удалить этого студента из БД?') == true) // Подтверждение удаления
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                utl: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Student")/' + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();

                        $.notify(data.message, { // Сообщение об успешном добавлении студента в БД
                            globalPosition: "top center", // Распологается поцентру
                            className: "success"
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Контроллер

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Student s = db.Student.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault<Student>();
        db.Student.Remove(s);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Данные о студенте удалены", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet }); // Сообщение уведомление
    }
```

Comment: Хм, может у Вас `id` неправильный.

Comment: HTML генерируется нормально, с правильными id

Comment: При чем здесь html? Как вызывается функция `Delete`?

Comment: <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin:0' onclick=Delete(" + data + ")>
<i class='fa fa-trash'></i>
Удалить
</a>

Comment: Добавьте в функцию `Delete` первой строчкой `console.log(id);`. Что Вы видите в консоли браузера?

Comment: Число, id элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в написании слова `url` в функции `$.ajax`, написано `utl`.

Исправленная версия

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Student")/' + id,
      success: function (data) {
```